# Pywinauto: unable to bring window to foreground

Tags: python, pywinauto

Working on the Python-powered automation tool.

Imagine there is a pool of apps running:

```
APPS_POOL = ['Chrome', 'SomeApp', 'Foo']
```

The script runs in the loop (every second) and needs to switch randomly between them:

```
# Init App object
app = application.Application()

# Select random app from the pull of apps
random_app = random.choice(APPS_POOL)
app.connect(title_re=".*%s" % random_app)
print 'Select "%s"' % random_app

# Access app's window object
app_dialog = app.window_(title_re=".*%s.*" % random_app)

if app_dialog.Exists():
    app_dialog.SetFocus()
```

The first time it works fine, but every other - the window would not be brought into foreground. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** the script is ran from Win7 CMD. Is it possible the system "blocks" CMD from setting focus somehow, once focus is set to other window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the `SetFocus` is a bit buggy. At least on my machine I get an error: `error: (87, 'AttachThreadInput', 'The parameter is incorrect.')`. So maybe you can play with Minimize/Restore. Notice that this approach is not bullet proof either.

```
import random
import time
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.findwindows import WindowAmbiguousError, WindowNotFoundError

APPS_POOL = ['Chrome', 'GVIM', 'Notepad', 'Calculator', 'SourceTree', 'Outlook']


# Select random app from the pull of apps
def show_rand_app():
    # Init App object
    app = application.Application()

    random_app = random.choice(APPS_POOL)
    try:
        print 'Select "%s"' % random_app
        app.connect(title_re=".*%s.*" % random_app)

        # Access app's window object
        app_dialog = app.top_window_()

        app_dialog.Minimize()
        app_dialog.Restore()
        #app_dialog.SetFocus()
    except(WindowNotFoundError):
        print '"%s" not found' % random_app
        pass
    except(WindowAmbiguousError):
        print 'There are too many "%s" windows found' % random_app
        pass

for i in range(15):
    show_rand_app()
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Nicely done @vitswd, it works! Looks like the `Focus()` is bugged indeed. Also, nice initiative with the `try..except`.

Comment: Just curious, how did you receive this error (console, did you try to debug)?

Comment: I played with your code in IPython and I saw the error above when SetFocus failed on

Comment: Any option for resizing the window when It's come on TOP

Answer (score 7):

above one is perfect answer, however HasStyle is deprecated the new method is as below

```
if m.has_style(win32defines.WS_MINIMIZE): # if minimized
    ShowWindow(m.wrapper_object(), 9) # restore window state
else:
    SetForegroundWindow(m.wrapper_object()) #bring to front
```

......
another way of dealing..

```
app = Application(backend='win32').connect(path="")
app.top_window().set_focus()
```

Answer (score 3):

As included in this issues

https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/785

`SetForegroundWindow` function has been deprecated in certain pywinauto version < 0.6.7 module. They've suggested to use `.set_focus()` in that blog

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(app_path)
app.top_window().set_focus()
```

or else suggested to use win32 module `SetForegroundWindow` function where even pywinauto using the same function in background.

```
import win32gui 
app = Application(backend='uia').start(app_path)
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys('%')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(app.top_window().handle)
```

In above mentioned code we can't use `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow` just like that before invoking that function we need to send *alt* key function so that `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow` function works properly and set application window to foreground.

Reference: https://www.codetd.com/en/article/7238534

Comment: I have tried this but getting `No windows for that process could be found` error. My code is as follows: `from pywinauto.application import Application, win32defines
from pywinauto.win32functions import ShowWindow
import win32gui, win32com.client 
def setup():
    app=Application(backend="uia")
    app.connect(path="C:\\Program Files\\MetaTrader 5\\terminal64.exe")
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    return app, shell
app, shell = setup()
shell.SendKeys('%')
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(app.top_window().handle)`

Comment: @AndyThompson Can you please paste your code in pastebin.com so that i can take look at in a clear manner.

Comment: @AndyThompson I have the same issue as you. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer didn't work properly in some cases - some apps based on Qt4-5 don`t load there GUI properly in some reason. So, i found another workaround of SetFocus() bug.

```
from pywinauto import Application, win32defines
from pywinauto.win32functions import SetForegroundWindow, ShowWindow

app = Application().connect(path="C:\path\to\process.exe")
w = app.top_window()

#bring window into foreground
if w.HasStyle(win32defines.WS_MINIMIZE): # if minimized
    ShowWindow(w.wrapper_object(), 9) # restore window state
else:
    SetForegroundWindow(w.wrapper_object()) #bring to front
```

Comment: Correct. I saw this issue for Qt5 app (WireShark). Will fix in pywinauto 0.6.4.